Why \AddToHook{env/figure/begin}{\centering} doesn't center the figures?
The LaTeX’s hook management's documentation (lthooks-doc.pdf) reads:

env/⟨env⟩/begin This hook is executed as part of \begin directly in front of the code
specific to the environment start (e.g., the third argument of \NewDocumentEnvironment
and the second argument of \newenvironment). Its scope is the environment body.

So I would have expected the “Foobar” figure to be centered in the following MCE:
\documentclass{article}
\AddToHook{env/figure/begin}{\centering}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  Foobar
  \caption{Foobar's caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}


Why isn't it the case?

The hook is executed before the environment's code, and \@float overwrites the code from \centering.

You could instead use \makeatletter \g@addto@macro\@floatboxreset\centering \makeatother

@campa Indeed, thanks for the insight. Though it doesn't provide an alternative, your comment answers my question :)

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz That is a nice trick! Is there a reason for not using \AddToHook{cmd/@floatboxreset/after}{\centering} instead?

@DenisBitouzé No reason, that was just what I had already sitting around, so copying was easier than typing :P (if you only want figures centred and not other floats, you might have to do it at the start of a figure)

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz ;) Unfortunately, this trick doesn't work with the standalone class. I'll ask a new question.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz do you want to answer? unless it is a duplicate?

@cfr I think an answer by campa would be better. The question as posted only asked about why, not how to solve it.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz oops, sorry. read too quickly.

@campa ^^ .....
